Nginx Reverse Proxy - Node Apps ( on port 3000, 3001, 3002 and 3003) Configuration
0
So i have 4 frontends that i needed to be accessed by public, but i want to specify an user friendly like example.com/lcd instead of example.com:3002. I want this for all those ports, 3001, 3000 and 3003 too. What i have now is the following example.pt.conf:
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.pt www.example.pt;

 location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

        location /window/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
        rewrite ^/window(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

     location /lcd/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002/;
        rewrite ^/lcd(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
  location /machine/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3003/;
        rewrite ^/machine(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

}
}

And a .conf for each frontend, with the same code as the following but with the diferent paths and ports:
server {

        listen 3003;
        listen [::]:3003;

        root /var/www/machine/build;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.pt  www.example.pt;

        location /machine/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
    }


So, what's the problem you're having?

your example conf file looks good. just listen at 80 or 443 (configure ssl certs) and you can proxy pass your servers running on any port (3000-3003).

thanks guys. I believe the problem is on the code, we need to update the routes. Thanks for all the help, i believe the conf i posted here is correct.
